# RavenDB - Como consultar palavras ignorando o acento

Tags: c#, sql, query

Preciso fazer uma consulta de nome de pessoa ignorando o acento.

Ex: no meu documento tenho um registro com o nome "Letícia". Caso eu consulte por "leticia" o resultado vem vazio. O comportamento que eu preciso é que encontre a pessoa mesmo que a consulta seja sem o acento.

```
session
   .Query<PersonResult, Person_Index>()
   .Search(r => r.FullName, $"*{name}*", escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowAllWildcards)
   .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<PersonResult>();
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o código da sua consulta atual??

Comment: Resolvi essa questão lendo este post do Elemar:
http://www.elemarjr.com/pt/2017/07/ravendb-consegue-falar-portugues/